# How to disable OpenVPN from running at startup on Raspbian?

Tags: raspbian, boot-issues, services, init.d

I'm trying to disable OpenVPN from running at startup. I tried changed the setting for `AUTOSTART` in `/etc/default/openvpn` from `all` to `none`, but that didn't work.

How do I disable OpenVPN from running at startup?

Comment: Check the file `/etc/init.d/openvpn` how it checks the values set from `/etc/default/openvpn`. Why do you want to disable it at system start? At what time should it start then?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using jessie, check:

```
systemctl list-units | grep vpn
```

You should be able to find the name of the service this way (wild guess: `openvpn`), then:

```
sudo systemctl disable openvpn
```

That won't stop it right now, but it should prevent it from starting next boot.  You will still be able to start it manually via `sudo systemctl start openvpn` (and stop it with `stop`).  If you want to re-enable it at boot, use `reenable`.